# How to install PHP8 XDebug in Opensuse tumbleweed?

Tags: php, xdebug, opensuse, php-8

I'm trying to debug a PHP script in PHP8. I've installed PHP8 and most of my dependencies. But there is no  php8-xdebug in the OpenSUSE repository.

Is it possible to install xdebug for PHP8?

Comment: I found that the XDbug binary exists for windows.

Comment: I also find a community package https://software.opensuse.org/package/php8-xdebug?search_term=php8-xdebug it may be not safe to install.

Comment: Deat @IMSoP tanks to your update.

Answer (score 1):

**parrot os debian linux**

Download the latest version of PHP from the official website (https://www.php.net/downloads.php).

Extract the downloaded archive:

```
tar -xvzf php-8.1.X.tar.gz
```

get those if don't have

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev
```

run the configure file

```
./configure
```

make it

```
make
sudo make install
```

you sould good to go inshaalla

```
php -v
```